# How to find the number of trials, given 1 success and the probability

Tags: probability

Okay, so the problem reads: '*A marksman hits a target 60% of the time and the outcome of each shot is
independent of the outcome of any other. What is the minimum number
of shots the marksman must take in order to be 90% sure that he will have
hit the target at least once?*'

My attempt at a solution is as follows:

I set up a Bernoulli trial with;
**n = n,
r = 1,
p = 0.6**

and I get the following:

***nC1*(0.6)*(.4)^(n-1) = 0.9***, which I then simplified to

***0.6n((.4^n)/0.4) = 0.9***

Where do I go from here as I have attempted to solve it numerous different ways and still have had no luck, have I made a mistake with the algebra somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Calcaulate the probability of $n$ consecutive failures for $n=1,2,3,...$ and stop, when it is not bigger than $0.1$.

A more elegant solution involves the logarithms. Solve $0.4^n\le 0.1$ by taking the logarithm on both sides to eventually get $n\ge 3$.

Comment: how did you end up with 0.4^n =< 0.1?

Comment: The probability of $n$ consecutive failures is $1$ - probability of at least $1$ success in $n$ tries. The probability of at least one success must be $\ge 0.9$, so that the probability of $n$ consecutive failures must be $\le 0.1$. And a failure has probability $0.4$.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!